# GetChanges() does not return rows

Tags: c#, dataset

I am trying to understand why there is no row value returned by `GetChanges()`. 
Row's values were changed using `row[column_name] = value`, `AcceptChanges()` was not called after.

What else should I check?

Comment: Please create an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show the actual problem here.

Comment: Have you tried to get the modified rows by filtering the result? `table.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);`